Flyout menu on hover, impossible to click child elements
I have created a menu with a flyout the appears on the right with the child elements. I've noticed, anyway, that there is a problem to click the child elements, in some case.
At this link if you select the last item ("PROFESSIONEL"). The item "blog" opens the flyout with the child elements but if the mouse moves toward the elements they disappear.
Surely I'm not practical enough with flyout, can somebody help me to solve this issue?
if possibile I would do it by CSS, I'm not practical enough with Javascript.
Thanks!
I've tryed to reduce the with of the link of the menu elements but clearly this is not the right solution.

Please provide code
